# Call Esper from my C program

Tags: c, interface, esper

Can some kind soul please show me a cookbook way that I can call Esper from my C program? Ideally (I think that) I'd like to call an Esper function/method with a line of EDL and get a value returned.

**EDIT:** i ask this question because I have 12,000 lines of working C code that I want to keep. Esper offers some really nice event evaluation that's crucial to my C code. JNI seems to be oriented toward calling C code from Java, maybe because C is faster for some things; I want to go the other way: to call Java code from C to take advantage of the power in the Java package, which is called Esper.

Thanks!

Comment: what *Esper* are you talking about? http://esper.codehaus.org/ seems to be a Java thing!

Comment: There is JNI http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface, but this assumes you'll write a lot of your code in Java and only the crucial parts in C.

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch -- Yes, Esper is a Java thing and that is the reason I am asking this question. I edited the question so that it makes more sense.

Comment: @Tom Dignan -- yeah, but in this case most of my code is in C and the crucial parts are in Java.

Comment: Try the Socket Adapter in EsperIO: http://esper.codehaus.org/esperio-4.4.0/doc/reference/en/html/adapter_socket.html Seems to be aimed more at getting events into Esper though; is that what you want? Otherwise, take the concept: sockets are one proven 'cookbook' way of implementing IPC and they save all that complicated messing with JNI.

Comment: @Tim Kemp -- What a great idea! Yeah, that's what I want to do: shovel a stream of events ***into***esper and get some kind of evaluation out. Beautiful! Thanks!

Comment: @Tim Kemp -- Hot damn! That's ***exactly*** what I was looking for! Thanks again!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the Socket Adapter in EsperIO: [doc link.](http://esper.espertech.com/release-7.1.0/esperio-reference/html/index.html) Seems to be aimed more at getting events into Esper though; is that what you want? Otherwise, take the concept: sockets are one proven 'cookbook' way of implementing IPC and they save all that complicated messing with JNI.